# automatically setting LaTeX package version for a release

Tags: package-writing

Making a release of a CTAN package sometimes requires updating the version in several places, which is error-prone.

Is there a tool/macro to support automation of this, e.g. from a git tag, or from a dedicated text file?

(e.g. in Python universe there is a tool called [versioneer](https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer), exactly for this purpose)

Comment: l3build can automate this, eg in any of the ho-tex packages l3build tag auto picks up the cuurent version and increments it, and sets the current date.